# Recovering the shape of a function $y = f(x)$ from measured values of $y$ as well as $\Delta y$ values associated to constant $\Delta x$ values?

Tags: integration, functions

Suppose I have a function $y = f(x)$ whose shape I don't know. It could be something like the following, but it could have any other shape:

[image]

There is a process that causes a point to move $\Delta X$ units to the right. Depending on where in the function you apply this $\Delta X$, the corresponding $\Delta Y$ will be different, as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the $\Delta X$ is always the same, even though the $\Delta Y$ changes.

I can do an experiment in which I am able to sample some Y values and their $\Delta Y$ values, that correspond to the process that induces a $\Delta X$ in the system. I cannot directly measure this $\Delta X$. Therefore, in my experiment, I end up with some data which I can plot like this:

[image]

My first question is: is there a way for me to recover the shape of the original function $y = f(x)$ and/or recover what $\Delta X$ is only from the data that I have? I suspect integrals might be involved here, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about this.

Furthermore, in this experiment I also managed to get data for a different process that induces a different amount of $\Delta X$ :

[image]

The resulting experimental data for this second process is something like this (notice the y axis is lower than before, because the induced $\Delta X$ is smaller:

[image]

My second question is: is there a way to compare the relative magnitudes in $\Delta X$ induced by the two different processes, even if I cannot recover the original magnitudes themselves?

If it helps, the data I used to simulate my experiment can be generated in R with the following code, although I'm more interested in the approach to solve this problem than in the actual solution:

```
Unknown.Function <- function(x){
  1/(1 + exp(-x))
}

Delta.X1 <- 2
X1 <- seq(-8,8,1)
Y1 <- Unknown.Function(x= X1)
Y1.Plus.Delta.X1 <-  Unknown.Function(x= X1 + Delta.X1)
Delta.Y1 <- Y1.Plus.Delta.X1 - Y1

Delta.X2 <- 1
X2 <- seq(-9,7,1)
Y2 <- Unknown.Function(x= X2)
Y2.Plus.Delta.X2 <-  Unknown.Function(x= X2 + Delta.X2)
Delta.Y2 <- Y2.Plus.Delta.X2 - Y2
```

**EDIT:**
 I am happy to interpolate a smooth function over the data that I already have ($\Delta Y$ and $Y$) so that I have an estimate of $\Delta Y = f(y)$, if this helps with getting back to the original $y = f(x)$ or at least to its shape.

Comment: If you Google "interpolation methods" you'll find endless resources.

Comment: Thanks. I can interpolate the shape of the $\Delta Y$ vs $Y$ function (e.g. using one of the methods here http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/). But then how do I go about going back to the original $y = f(x)$ function? Is that also an interpolation problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  There is no way of knowing what $f(x)$ is from its values at finitely many points.  Essentially, you have to assume it's a reasonably smooth function, and try to find an approximation to it.  You basically find a function $y$ that is close to $f$ in some sense, and use $y$ as a surrogate for $f$.  Of course, if the assumption that $f$ is well-behaved is mistaken, then $y$ will not be a good approximation at all.

Comment: I have data for $\Delta y$ and for $y$. I can fit in a smooth curve to those data (e.g. a loess regression, a smooth spline...). I now have an approximation for $\Delta y = f(y)$. For this function, I also know that every $\Delta y$ originates from $\Delta x$ values of the same magnitude. I now want to estimate $y = f(x)$

Comment: If you're trying to approximate your data by a continuous function $f(x)$, then you will need to use some kind of regression technique from Statistics. Once you have found the approximation $f(x)$ of your data you can then choose to use it as a model for your data, and get whatever $\Delta X$ or $\Delta Y$'s you want from it. If, however, you're saying that you have the $\Delta X$ and $\Delta Y$'s from which you want to find $f(x)$, then you will need to create the data points using the $\Delta$'s first, then use a Statistical regression method to find $f(x)$.

Comment: See, e.g., https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/curve-fitting-linear-nonlinear-regression/

Comment: Thanks @Pixel . I do not have $\Delta X$ values. I only have $\Delta Y$ and $y$. The only thing I know is that $\Delta X $ is always the same. Suppose that I (arbitrarily) decide that my $\Delta X$ values are all 1. I now have a set of $\Delta X$ and $\Delta Y$ values from which I want to try and find $y=f(x)$. How can I create the $x$ and $y$ points before finding $f(x)$ ?

Comment: @Ender Are your $\Delta Y$ values in order (corresponding to increasing $x$ values) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your comments this may be what you're looking for.

Suppose $\Delta Y_i$ corresponds to $x_i$, and **suppose** that $x_{i+1}>x_i$ with $x_{i+1}-x_i=\Delta X$.)

Then choose $x_0=0$ and set your $\Delta X=1$ for sake of argument, so that the distance between successive $x_i$ values is exactly $\Delta X=1$.

Then you can construct the following set of points,

$$(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$$
$$(x_1,y_1)=(\Delta X,\Delta Y_1)$$
$$(x_2,y_2)=(x_1 + \Delta X,y_1 + \Delta Y_2)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$(x_n,y_n)=(x_{n-1} + \Delta X,y_{n-1} + \Delta Y_n)$$
$$\vdots$$

That is to say, for each new point, just add $\Delta X$ to the previous $x$ value, and add the next $\Delta Y$ value to the previous $y$ value.

At the end you have a set of points

$$\{(x_n,y_n)\mid n=0,1,2,\ldots\},$$

which you can apply a regression technique to to find your curve of best fit.

Note, however, that if we cannot assume the $x$ values to be ordered then how are we to know where the $(x,y)$ values actually lie? In such a case your data could represent any (finite) number of functions.

Comment: thanks! I've been playing around with this and I think this works for the purposes of what I wanted to do!

Comment: @Ender Glad it helped. Note that for any curves with $y$ values that go up and down (like in your last image in your question post) then the $\Delta Y_i$'s need to be able to be positive and **negative**, depending on how the curve is changing relative to the most recent $y$ value.

Comment: PS you could use, e.g. Nadaraya-Watson estimator to construct a continuous function from the discrete data !